# Ruby on Rails Active Record Join

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I need to joins this two tables but I cant seems to get it right.

Model

`class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :region
 end`

`class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :registration
end`

what I have tried so far is this

```
`test = Region.joins(:registration)`
```

which will give me this result

`[#<Region id: 1, name: "region1">, #<Region id: 1, name: "region1">]`

It seem that i have certainly did join the two tables but my dilemma is I also need the index that belongs to Registration Model. the about results are only the index available in the Region Model.

I also tried it the other way around

`test = Registration.joins(:region)`

but it gives me a error

`Unknown column 'regions.registration_id' in 'on clause': SELECT`registrations`.* FROM`registrations`INNER JOIN`regions`ON`regions`.`registration_id`=`registrations`.`id``

and I do agree with this error cause i do not have a index registration_id

Answer (score 0):

when you define belongs_to relationship in a table that table should have foreign_key of table to which it is belonging. So in your example if you have relation like Region belongs to registrations then regions should have registration_id. It looks like you have defined a wrong relationship.

So if you will define registration_id in Region and execute following query:

```
Region.joins(:registration)
```

You will see id of region table along with registration_id in the result

Hope this helps

Comment: the table look like this 

Registration : | id | region_id | name | 
Region: | id | name | 

so how should i define them on my models ?

Comment: Ohh.. then you should have has_many :registrations in Region model and belongs_to :region in Registration model. Then you can execute query Registration.joins(:region)

Comment: Im still getting the same error when running `Registration.joins(:region)` it keeps looking for a registration_id column

Comment: Can you please tell me How you have defined relationship in model?

Comment: did it like this 

`class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :registrations
end` 

`class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :region
end`

Answer (score 0):

Change the `Registration model` code

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :regions
end
```

Then you can use `joins`

```
test = Registration.joins(:region)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :regions, inverse_of: :registration, dependent: :destroy
 end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :registration, inverse_of: :regions
end
```

Then, make sure your `Region` table correctly shows its association to `Registration` with a `registration_id` column. If it doesn't contain the column, go ahead and create the following migration:

`rails g migration add_registration_ref_to_regions registration:references`

`rake db:migrate`

Now, you should be able to successfully query via:

`Registration.joins(:regions)` or `Region.joins(:registration)`

Cheers!